# Misentered the site address url. How to recover?

Tags: urls, options

I managed to enter a wrong *Site Address (URL)*  on the *General Settings* page and now I can't even visit the website. I'm doing this on OpenShift/RedHat.

How do I recover?

[image: settings]

Comment: If you made a mistake in the DNS, you need to fix at the DNS level, not the WordPress level. Is that what you meant, or did you make an error when creating the WordPress site?

Comment: I made a mistake in Wordpress settings where I accidentely changed the wordpress address

Comment: See wordpress URL here http://i.stack.imgur.com/iwNP5.png

Comment: When the options are grayed out like that it is sometimes because the site home and address have been defined in the `wp-config.php` file (root of your wp install). Open that file and look for:  `define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.mysitename.com/myblog' );` and `define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://www.mysitename.com' );`

Answer (score 1):

The best way to fix this is to install PHPmyAdmin and then navigate to the wp-options table and change the site-address row.

To install PHPmyAdmin, click on "Browse Marketplace" and search for PHPmyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

@Pat Gilmour is on the right track. The source to handle this is [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL).

First thing you want to do is open the `wp-config.php`file in your SFTP (secure FTP).

Add these two lines to your `wp-config.php`, where "example.com" is the correct location of your site.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Read that whole page for all the data.

Answer (score 0):

Add `phpMyAdmin` to your application. (it should be under **Tools and Support**). The phpmyadmin username and password will be the same as the MySQL credentials. Login to phpmyadmin and go to **wp_options** table ..... Check the rest on WP official url change docs.

[image: phpMyAdmin Enabled]

> If a scalable application is created, the scaling function of that
>   application cannot be disabled. phpmyadmin-4 cannot be embedded in
>   scalable app

### Alternative Method

Or Generate ssh and use filezilla or putty to access your files. [Details](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-remote-connection.html)

For filezilla - File > Site Manager >

- Hostname = your rhc subdomain
- Protocol = SFTP
- Login Type = Key file
- User = can be found at application page
- Key file = select **.ppk** file which you generated by puttygen

After connect go to the following path and modify `wp-config.php`

```
/var/lib/openshift/*username*/app-root/data/current
```

Enjoy

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. Please extend your answer and explain how it solves the problem. Thanks

Comment: Hi @birgire, i've edited the answer. Hope this will work better.

Comment: good effort and great you took the time to update your answer,  It would be nice to have a little bit more detail on what do to in the `wp_options` table and what to do in the `wp-config.php` file.

Comment: I think what to do is already described in the above answers and I stated to check wp official url change docs. I was actually describing what is difficult part.